# SQL General Optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-optimization

recently was asked to help with query optimization

The table looks like this:

```
create table dbo.Table
( 
 id int identity primary key clustered ,
 column_1 varchar(64) not null  ,
 Date datetime not null ,
 Column_2 varchar (32) not null ,
 Column_3 int not null 
)
```

and select looks like

`select * from Table where column_1 = @value1 and Date > @value2`

I propose to show columns names instead of `*` in select , because it can help avoid loading unneeded data, also propose `create nonclustered index` on column_1. However, execution plan still shows the same amount of memory used by query.

What else should I check or add into the query?

Answer (score 2):

You can optimize the query by using indexes.  The one you want would be on `column_1` and `date`:

```
create index idx_table_column1_date on table(column_1, date);
```

Comment: i already create them (composite index) but execution plane didn't change, is there anything else i should check? or i should create separate indexes for  column_1 and date columns

Comment: What's the execution plan say?

Comment: @Andrey How many rows in the table? How many match the predicate? What is the datatype of `@value1`?

Comment: @MartinSmith I generate 1000000 rows in the table `@value1` is varchar which declared and looks like 'HR'

Comment: @Andrey - How many of them match the condition? Also are you sure your query is using `=` not `LIKE`? Your comment originally said `'%HR%'`

Comment: @MartinSmith sorry  to confuse you `@value1` = 'HR' I generate 1 mil records (with loop statment) and 43 000 rows are matching

Comment: That's 4.3%. This might be over the tipping point. Do you get a seek if you do `SELECT column_1, date` with the same `WHERE` clause (instead of `SELECT *`)?

Comment: @MartinSmith what you mean by tipping point? you think after this point my indexes useless?

Comment: @Andrey - See [Why aren’t those nonclustered indexes being used?](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/why-arent-those-nonclustered-indexes-being-used/)

Comment: @MartinSmith execution plan show me same numbers if I use `select * ` or `select column_1`

Comment: @Andrey  Actually I just noticed this bit in your question "execution plan still shows the same amount of memory used by query". Quite possibly you are focussing on some number that doesn't make any sense to be focussing on.  Both queries will just require minimal amounts of memory anyway if you are looking at the memory grant figure. You should be looking at things like scan vs seek.

Comment: @MartinSmith I noticed strange ting execution plane still show me that its doing scan by clustered index which is on ID column, looks like its not using nonclustered at all